# One field among multiple fields not updating with save function, Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

In below piece of code, I tried to save some fields of a model and Before calling the save method I update one of fields by using another instance of same model.

But `is_owner` remains 0 even after save method call, but other fields get updated.

```
$deviceAssignedData = \App\DeviceAssignment::where('user_id', $user_id)->where('device_id', $device->id)->latest('created_at')->first();

if($deviceAssignedData){

    \App\DeviceAssignment::where('device_id', $device->id)->update(['is_owner' => 0]);

    $deviceAssignedData->acknowledge_status = 1;
    $deviceAssignedData->acknowledge_date = Carbon::now();
    $deviceAssignedData->is_owner = 1;
    $deviceAssignedData->save();

}
```

Can somebody suggest whats wrong i am doing here?

> Note : In one condition its working fine when `is_owner` of selected row was previously `0` then save() method update this to `1` perfectly.

Comment: Have you made is_owner column fillable ?

Comment: @SagarGautam Having `protected $guarded = [];` in my model

Comment: Are you using database transcation ?

Comment: @SagarGautam No. Added note in question.

Comment: If is_owner is previously 0 then it will update to 1. If there is is_owner field is already 1 then it will not update

Comment: Yes, Its looks like if selected row get affected by this code `\App\DeviceAssignment::where('device_id', $device->id)->update(['is_owner' => 0]);`
 Then followed save() function does not update `is_owner` column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `is_owner` into `$fillable` variable in the model, then you would be able to use `->update()` function.

```
class DeviceAssignment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'is_owner',
    ];
}
```

Comment: I already have `protected $guarded = [];` in my model. So, No need to add $fillable property. And my update function working fine only issue is with save() method.